# How do I use conditional logic with Datetime columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, datetime

I have two datetime columns - ColumnA and ColumnB. I want to create a new column - ColumnC, using conditional logic.

Originally, I created ColumnB from a YearMonth column of dates such as 201907, 201908, etc.

When ColumnA is NaN, I want to choose ColumnB.
Otherwise, I want to choose ColumnA.

Currently, my code below is causing ColumnC to have different formats. I'm not sure how to get rid of all of those 0's. I want the whole column to be YYYY-MM-DD.

```
    ID  YearMonth  ColumnA      ColumnB     ColumnC
0   1   201712     2017-12-29   2017-12-31  2017-12-29
1   1   201801     2018-01-31   2018-01-31  2018-01-31
2   1   201802     2018-02-28   2018-02-28  2018-02-28
3   1   201806     2018-06-29   2018-06-30  2018-06-29
4   1   201807     2018-07-31   2018-07-31  2018-07-31
5   1   201808     2018-08-31   2018-08-31  2018-08-31
6   1   201809     2018-09-28   2018-09-30  2018-09-28
7   1   201810     2018-10-31   2018-10-31  2018-10-31
8   1   201811     2018-11-30   2018-11-30  2018-11-30
9   1   201812     2018-12-31   2018-12-31  2018-12-31
10  1   201803     NaN          2018-03-31  1522454400000000000
11  1   201804     NaN          2018-04-30  1525046400000000000
12  1   201805     NaN          2018-05-31  1527724800000000000
13  1   201901     NaN          2019-01-31  1548892800000000000
14  1   201902     NaN          2019-02-28  1551312000000000000
15  1   201903     NaN          2019-03-31  1553990400000000000
16  1   201904     NaN          2019-04-30  1556582400000000000
17  1   201905     NaN          2019-05-31  1559260800000000000
18  1   201906     NaN          2019-06-30  1561852800000000000
19  1   201907     NaN          2019-07-31  1564531200000000000
20  1   201908     NaN          2019-08-31  1567209600000000000
21  1   201909     NaN          2019-09-30  1569801600000000000
```

```py
df['ColumnB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YearMonth'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce').dropna() + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) 

df['ColumnC'] = np.where(pd.isna(df['ColumnA']), pd.to_datetime(df['ColumnB'], format='%Y%m%d'), df['ColumnA'])
```

Answer (score 0):

df['ColumnC'] = np.where(df['ColumnA'].isnull(),df['ColumnB'] , df['ColumnA'])

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this produced the same results as my results above. I ended up figuring it out - needed to convert columnA to datetime too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out!

```py
df['ColumnC'] = np.where(pd.isna(df['ColumnA']), pd.to_datetime(df['ColumnB']), pd.to_datetime(df['ColumnA']))
```